# How do I add external library/includes with postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am currently working with file_fdw of Postgres where makefile is like below:

```
MODULES = test_fdw
EXTENSION = test_fdw
DATA = test_fdw--1.0.sql
PGFILEDESC = "test_fdw - foreign data wrapper for files"
REGRESS = test_fdw
EXTRA_CLEAN = sql/test_fdw.sql expected/test_fdw.out
ifdef USE_PGXS
    PG_CONFIG = pg_config
    PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
    include $(PGXS)
else
    subdir = contrib/test_fdw
    top_builddir = ../..
    include $(top_builddir)/src/Makefile.global
    include $(top_srcdir)/contrib/contrib-global.mk
endif
```

I want to add some C/C++ external library and includes with my project.
How can I change this makefile?

Answer (score 0):

Set `CFLAGS` to contain the include directives and `LDFLAGS` to contain link directives needed for the shared library.

Be careful when linking C++ code into PostgreSQL; see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html#EXTEND-CPP).